# VS 2010 Add second page to .rdlc report

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, rdlc, reporting-services

I have an existing report that works fine.  I"ve been asked to add a second page to the report that displays a mailing address.  I just need a second blank page with a mailing address.

I'm using visual studio and the report is a .rdlc file.

How do I add the second page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a new table to contain the address information and set the `PageBreak` property to `"Start"`.